# RowVirtualization cause incorrect background color for rows

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, virtualization, xbap

I have a WPF application and there is a Datagrid in some pages. This datagrid needs to load 5000 rows at once (Pagination is not an option for me) and this takes ages. I set EnableRowVirtualization=True and the performance is acceptable now, but there is a problem here.
In my datagrid I need to set different background colors to different rows depending on a column value (say STATUS), changing EnableRowVirtualization from False to True, caused incorrect coloring when I scroll.

----Edit----

Here is my XAML code:

```
<my:DataGrid Name="dgDataGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader" 
                     CanUserDeleteRows="True" RowHeight="20" SelectionMode="Extended"  SelectionUnit="FullRow" FontFamily="Tahoma" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding}"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                     EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" BorderBrush="Blue"  
                     RowBackground="White" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Blue"  GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Blue"  
                     IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsTabStop="True" HeadersVisibility="All" Loaded="dgDataGrid_Loaded"  
                     ContextMenuOpening="dgDataGrid_ContextMenuOpening" LoadingRow="dgDataGrid_LoadingRow" 
                     ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled ="True">
            <my:DataGrid.Resources>

            </my:DataGrid.Resources>

            <my:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:DataGridRow}}, Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <my:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="my:DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </my:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <my:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="cmDataGrid" StaysOpen="True">
                    <MenuItem Name="mnuView" Header="نمایش">
                        <MenuItem Name="mnuHideColumn"  Header="Hide Column" Click="mnuHideColumn_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Name="mnuShowColumn" Header="Show Column"/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Name="mnuGroupByColumn" 
                          Header="Group by this column" Click="mnuGroupColumn_Click" />
                        <MenuItem Name="mnuClearGroups" 
                          Header="Clear grouping" Click="mnuGroupColumn_Click" />
                        <Separator/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Header Alignment">
                            <MenuItem Name="mnuHeaderCenter" Header="Center"/>
                            <MenuItem Name="mnuHeaderLeft" Header="Left"/>
                            <MenuItem Name="mnuHeaderRight" Header="Right"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Content Alignment">
                            <MenuItem Name="mnuContentCenter" Header="Center"/>
                            <MenuItem Name="mnuContentLeft" Header="Left"/>
                            <MenuItem Name="mnuContentRight" Header="Right"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </my:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </my:DataGrid>
```

and following codes do the bindings:

Note: all my columns are getting generated on the fly depends on the object requested to be loaded:

```
public static DataGridColumn CreateTextBoxWithBackgroudColumn(DataColumn dataCol, string columnName)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            dgtc.Header = columnName;
            dgtc.HeaderStyle = (Style)(App.Current as App).FindResource("ColumnHeaderStyle");

            FrameworkElementFactory cellTemplateFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            Binding dataBinding = new Binding(dataCol.ColumnName);
            dataBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            dataBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

            dataBinding.Converter = new BackGroundConverter();

            cellTemplateFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, dataBinding);
            DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            cellTemplate.VisualTree = cellTemplateFactory;
            cellTemplate.Seal();
            dgtc.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

            return dgtc;
        }
```

The returned DataGridColumn will be added to my DataGrid columns.

Is that possible to have both RowVirtualization and coloring at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try using snoop ? post code sample otherwise its really hard to guess what wrong

Comment: The point is RowVirtualization never create a new displaying page, it gets the next page of fields and put them in previous page frame and so on. Therefore all row color bindings mismatches if you scroll down and up couple of times.
Disabling it, will solve the problem but the performance goes down dramatically!
What I am not sure about is there any trick to go around this and have them both at the same time?

Comment: there shouldn't be any binding mismatching, post the relevant code

Comment: I would start with creating the column statically in XAML and if the problem is the dynamic cretin, post the code for the color changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RowVirtualization is not working well for row background coloring, I added a column and colored it instead of whole row.

Answer (score 8):

This may be a bit too late for you since you apparently found a working solution for you, but hopefully it can help others. I had a similar problem just now and after some googling found out that the reason for this behaviour is that the default value for [VirtualizationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode.aspx) is `Recycling`. This means that item containers are reused and thus the coloring of the background will stick even if the item that occupies the container after scrolling says it should not be colored.

To solve this simply set the `VirtualizationMode` to `Standard`, like so:

```
<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
```

The containers will then be recreated and destroyed when you scroll, applying any changes you do in the `LoadingRow` event.

Comment: Thanks @Eirik. I went through this way as well, but this was causing performance issues and also one other problem I cant recall right now.

Comment: @amirmoradifard yeah, there's obviously a performance hit due to the containers being recreated and destroyed over and over compared to just reuse the ones that's allready created. This is important to be aware of if performance is important.

Comment: So far i dont see any double colored rows anymore... In comparison to no virtualization mode the 'standard' mode is still a speed increase.

Answer (score 2):

Well as [Eirik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773118/eirik) said it might be too late. but i would be glad if it can help others.
You can do this EnableRowVirtualization = "True" (so it won't affect your performance in case of large data). And just code this on dgOrders_LoadingRow event.

```
private void dgOrders_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{

        OrderDetail item = e.Row.Item as OrderDetail; //parse data into your bject type which is 
        if (item != null)
        {
             if (item.Note== "Loss") //your condition
             {
                 e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;
             }
             else                    //otherwise default color
             {
                 e.Row.Background = Brushes.White;
             }
        }
    }
```